# jQuery.validationEngine reference error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Everything seems to be referenced correctly however I can't get it to work properly. Strangely it worked once but took 10 seconds before the validation message popped up, didn't change anything and tried again but stop working. The only warning i have is `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` in the jQuery library.

```
<html>

 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
   </head>

<body>

    <form id="formID">
        <input class="validate[required]" type="text" id="agree" name="agree"/>
    </form>

 <script src='js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script src="jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formID").validationEngine();
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

If there is nothing wrong with the above then it may be something else in my project interfering, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check [jQuery bug #14320](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320). Seems like it should be fixed in a future release. Chrome and Firefox suffer the same issue.

Comment: using jQuery lib 1.11.0 got rid of warning however still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case as I mentioned above updating to [jQuery lib 1.11.0](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js) rid the warning for me. (latest chrome)

Here is how I ended up using the validationEngine if interested:

```
<form id="formID" />
<button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="clicked(event);">Submit Survey</button>

function clicked (e) 
    {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) 
        {
           if ($("#formID").validationEngine('validate'))
           {
               my.LocalStorage.save(); 
           }
        }   
        e.preventDefault();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening, probably, is at the time jQuery is loaded your plugin(s) aren't yet loaded so when you call the `validationEngine()` method, it's not yet defined. I recommend loading your scripts synchronously with [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) and call that method once both scripts have loaded.

If you stick with the Modernizr way all you need to do is include your minimized version of Modernizr in the head and call your scripts like below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Your Document</title>
        <!--
            following script loads first. nevermind the version, I copied it from a script of mine
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="formID">
            <!-- etc -->
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Modernizr.load([
            {
                // following loads next
                load: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
                complete: function() {
                    if (!window.jQuery) Modernizr.load('js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
                    // this is your local copy of jQuery, in case you might need a fallback
                }
            },{
                // finally the remaining scripts load
                load:[
                    'jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js',
                    'jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js'
                ],
                complete: function() {
                    // all is loaded. do what you want here.
                    $("#formID").validationEngine();
                }
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```